# mongodb Query in c# using in operator

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I am trying to convert mongodb native query in c# using their driver but somehow its not producing correct results.

```
db.food.find
(
{
    $and:[
     {min_price:{$gte:1}}
    ,{max_price:{$lte:50}}
    ,{food:{$in:["sausage","burger"]}}
    ,{location:{$in:["new york","chicago"]}}
    ]
}
)
```

Could someone please help me out with c# code on this ?

Comment: any C# code, please?

Answer (score 0):

According [the documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-csharp-driver/#csharp-driver-tutorial), you can try [`Query.And` method with params](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/323f9430-efe3-9726-c77a-d201a7a3e6eb.htm), in which you pass single `Query` object, something like this:

```
var food = server.GetDatabase("food", credentials);
var col = db.GetCollection<RawBsonDocument>("bar");
foreach (var doc in col.Find(
    Query.And(
        Query.GTE("min_price", 1),
        Query.LTE("max_price", 50),
        Query.In("food", new [] { (BsonValue)"sausage", (BsonValue)"burger" }),
        Query.In("location", new [] { (BsonValue)"new york", (BsonValue)"chicago" })
    ))
)
{
    // handle found doc here
}
```

in this example I've used the `RawBsonDocument` class, but you can use `LazyBsonDocument` if your data is big. An implicit operators from `string` to `BsonValue` are implemented, and you can use then in `.In` method.

[Full documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/).